# Why member functions of a local class can access the function arguments but not local variables?

Tags: c++

A local class is the one which is declared (as well as defined) inside a function. The methods (member functions) of this local class can access the static members, but not the local variables of the function in which it is defined. As far as I understand the arguments passed to a function are treated as local variables (they have function scope), then why is it that these arguments can be accessed by the methods of the local class?

For instance, in the below example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void rectangleAreaPerimeter(float l, float b)
{
    class Calculate
    {
        float area;
        float perimeter;

        public:
        void calculateArea(float l, float b)
        {
            area = l * b;
        }

        void calculatePerimeter(float l, float b)
        {
            perimeter = 2 * (l + b);
        }

        void print()
        {
            cout << "Area: " << area << " sq units" << "Perimeter: " << perimeter << " units.";
        }
    };

    Calculate AreaPerimeter;

    AreaPerimeter.calculateArea(l,b);
    AreaPerimeter.calculatePerimeter(l,b);
    AreaPerimeter.print();
}

int main()
{
    float length = 1.2;
    float breadth = 1.2;

    rectangleAreaPerimeter(length, breadth);
    return 0;
}
```

l and b are passed as arguments to the function rectangleAreaPerimeter(), and therefore are local to this function. Then why are the methods calculateArea() and calculatePerimeter() of the Calculate class able to access these variables?

```
Output:
Area: 1.44 sq units Perimeter: 4.8 units
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The `l` and `b` are passed as arguments to `calculateArea` so they can be used there. These are not the same variables as the arguments of `rectangleAreaPerimeter`.  Maybe if you used different names, it'll be clearer what's going on.

Comment: "Then why are the methods calculateArea() and calculatePerimeter() of the Calculate class able to access these variables?" They are not. Just do not name all parameters the same and you will see the difference.

Comment: @Slava i have just explained the reason  for his question with his sample, please don't complain about others, instead of that ,try to give the proper explanation for the query.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

reference to a local variable of function to class is not allowed,  i have explained your question in the below link
[reference to a local variable of enclosing function is not allowed](https://svsivan.blogspot.com/2020/07/reference-to-local-variable-of.html)

Comment: If you want to provide source code then add it to the answer directly, and don't use external links. The answer has to include all the necessary information to answer the question without the need to follow the link.